# HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler is not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my spring boot project, I've created a class extending  `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`

With the following code (simplified for brevity)

```
public class ModelResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter returnType) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Then in my Config class did:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers) {
        handlers.add(new ModelResolver());
    }
}
```

Then in my integration test method, simply created a mockMvc like the following

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(BASE_URL + "create"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andReturn();
```

but `handleReturnValue` is not called.

I put break points  in `addReturnValueHandlers` of configuration and also inside `supportsReturnType` and `handleReturnValue`.

The one inside `addReturnValueHandlers` is caught, but neither `supportsReturnType` nor `handleReturnValue` is not caught!

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var requestMappingHandlerAdapter: RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

@PostConstruct
fun init() {
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.returnValueHandlers?.let { returnValueHandlers ->
            val newReturnValueHandlers = ArrayList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>(returnValueHandlers.size + 1)
            newReturnValueHandlers.add(0, ApiReturnHandler(requestMappingHandlerAdapter.messageConverters))
            newReturnValueHandlers.addAll(returnValueHandlers)
            requestMappingHandlerAdapter.returnValueHandlers = newReturnValueHandlers
        }

    }
```

Comment: please explain answers on stack